# Parser Mismatched Metadata

Tags: html, facebook, squarespace

I've entered my website into Facebook's Debugger and I get the following warning message that I do not understand how I'm supposed to fix:

The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:title, og:description'

I've searched the forums here but the answers provided were for different errors and I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: What is the URL you input?

Comment: https://estadoslatinosdeamerica.com/

Comment: This is what Facebook sees https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Festadoslatinosdeamerica.com%2F . You have og:title there 3 times

Comment: Yeah :( I know. I am not sure where exactly it is pulling it from so many times!

Comment: Because your server is outputting it many times. Don't do that

Comment: I found the issue. I had custom code injection in two different places. 

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had custom code injection in two different places: the main page and the home page. Once I fixed that the issue disappeared.